# 'is not iterable' Using hooks to make an API call from seperate folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I create a small app that before had pre-created data. `const users = { [id:1, name: ... etc` but I decided to go a little further and use the api `https://randomuser.me` that way I could at least play around with some of the Hooks that React provides.

However in my playing around it seems I've ran into an error that I cannot seem to understand. I've logged out my API call and I am getting the `users` back, but I'm not able to place them in the table next to it.

There is a few files so I will add them all to make it readable.

Once again the error I'm getting intially is 'users is not iterable' when I click the Add User button, as well as it showing on load up that there isn't any new users, when I can see the API call has fired and logged that it does have users pulled from the API

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import UserTable from './tables/UserTable'
import AddUserForm from './forms/AddUserForm'
import { getUsers } from './services/getUsers.services'

const App = () => {

const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getUsers().then(users => {
        setUsers(users);
        console.log(users)
        }); 
  }, []);




const addUser = (user) => {
    user.id = users.length + 1 
    setUsers([...users, user])
}


  return (
    <div className="container">
        <h1> CRUD with Hooks :)</h1>
        <div className="flex-row"> 
            <div className="flex-large">
                <h2>Add user</h2>
                <AddUserForm addUser={addUser} />
            </div>
            <div className="flex-large">
                <h2>View Users</h2>
                <UserTable users={users} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

getUsers.services.js

```
export const getUsers = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5');
    return data.json()
}
```

addUserForm

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const AddUserForm = (props) => {

const initialFormState = {id: null, name: '', username: ''}

const [user,setUser] = useState(initialFormState)

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const {name , value} = event.target
    setUser({...user, [name]: value })
 }
    return (
        <form
        onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            if (!user.name || !user.username) return

            props.addUser(user)
            setUser(initialFormState)
        
        }}
        >
            <label>Name</label>
            <input 
            type='text' 
            name='name' 
            value={user.name}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <label>Username</label> 
            <input 
            type='text' 
            name='username' 
            value={user.username}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <button>Add New User</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default AddUserForm
```

UserTable.js

```
import React from 'react'

const UserTable = (props) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      {props.users.length > 0 ? (
        props.users.map((user) => (
          <tr key={user.id}>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.username}</td>
            <td>
              <button className="button muted-button">Edit</button>
              <button className="button muted-button">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))
      ) : (
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={3}>No users</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
  </table>
)

export default UserTable
```

Comment: Looks like that API returns an object. Shouldn't it be `users.results`?

Comment: @jayce444 where would that be put?

Comment: In your `getUsers` function, you should return the results array rather than `data.json()`. Maybe just use `.then` format for it so it's consistent, i.e. `export const getUsers = () => fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.results);`